# Working with lower version of GLIBC: version `GLIBC_2.11` not found (required by g++)

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, glibc, rhel

I've installed GCC 7.1 on my machine and tried to use `g++` on it, but it didn't work, saying this:

```
g++: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.11` not found (required by g++)
```

So then I did these:

```
 $ strings /lib64/lib.so.6 | grep GLIB
 GLIBC_2.2.5
 GLIBC_2.2.6
 GLIBC_2.3
 GLIBC_2.3.2
 GLIBC_2.3.3
 GLIBC_2.3.4
 GLIBC_2.4
 GLIBC_2.5
 GLIBC_PRIVATE

 $ strings `which g++` | grep GLIB
 GLIBC_2.3
 GLIBC_2.11
 GLIBC_2.2.5
```

Two things can be noted here:

- The string `GLIBC_2.11` isn't common to both of these outputs.
- However, `GLIBC_2.3` is common to both.

Questions:

**1.** What exactly do these strings mean? Why are there more than one string in both of them? What do they tell us?

**2.** My *guess* is that the absence of `GLIBC_2.11` in `libc` explains why `g++` doesn't work, as `g++` requires it (as the error says itself). However, I'm confused what does the presence of `GLIBC_2.3` in both actually mean? Does it mean that `g++` can be instructed to use this instead of `GLIBC_2.11`? If so, how exactly? What is the command?

Comment: The gcc you installed has been built for a system that provides a newer glibc than what's on your system, trying to make it work on your system is not a fun way to spend the better part of a weekend - You are much better off finding a package that works on your system, or build gcc .7.1 from source on your system.

Answer (score 4):

`GLIBC_2.3` and `GLIBC_2.11` are symbol versions.  The dynamic linker uses them to perform a quick check for library compatibility at program startup: the system glibc must provide all symbol versions referenced by the program.   Your glibc is apparently 2.5 (which would match Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5).  This version lacks quite a few features added in later versions, and it turns out the pre-compiled GCC binary you are trying to run needs some of them.

To resolve this, you'll need a version of GCC compiled specifically for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.  I haven't tried if the current GCC upstream sources build with the system compiler, which is … quite ancient by this time (although upstream still sticks with C++03 for exactly such needs).  Some `libstdc++` functionality may also need a newer kernel than 2.6.18, and some care is necessary to preserve compatibility between the new `libstdc++` and the one installed with the system.